# want to show xsl node data as it is

Tags: xml, xslt

I have data in XML and I want to show that **as it is** in the browser using XSL file what should I do. in below data i want to show comments as it is. The data is:

```
<RESULT_COMMENTS>EBV Acute EBV Acute Infection Antibodies
Reported: 11/23/2016 18:08   Status=F
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST                      RESULT               FLAG  RANGE       UNITS      SC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EBV Ab VCA, IgM           &lt;36.0                      0.0-35.9     U/mL      RN      11/23/16.1808.rf
Negative        &lt;36.0
Equivocal 36.0 - 43.9
Positive        &gt;43.9
EBV Early Antigen Ab, IgG &lt;9.0                       0.0-8.9      U/mL      RN      11/23/16.1808.rf
Negative        &lt; 9.0
Equivocal  9.0 - 10.9
Positive        &gt;10.9
EBV Ab VCA, IgG           &lt;18.0                      0.0-17.9     U/mL      RN      11/23/16.1808.rf
Negative        &lt;18.0
Equivocal 18.0 - 21.9
Positive        &gt;21.9
EBV Nuclear Antigen Ab,   &lt;18.0                      0.0-17.9     U/mL      RN      11/23/16.1808.rf
IgG
Negative        &lt;18.0
Equivocal 18.0 - 21.9
Positive        &gt;21.9
Interpretation:                                                             RN      11/23/16.1808.rf</RESULT_COMMENTS>
```

Comment: I have xml file in which data is placed well formatted and an xsl file. what should i do with xsl that in browser data is shown as formatted as in xml

Comment: Welcome to SO  @mian-asif! I don't understand what you want. What you show is not xml (starts with "EBV..." and not with <somerootelement>) and if you want to show it as-is, why use xslt? Opening xml in a browser will normally display it "as-is" maybe with a message that there is no stylesheet associated and that's why it is showing it as-is... - if you absolutely want to use xslt, what you are looking for is called "identity transform", should give several hits here

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you mean by "show the data **as it is**". I would have expected the table to be padded with spaces, so that the columns will  align when presented in a mono-spaced font. That's easy to do using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="RESULT_COMMENTS">
    <pre>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </pre>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result will look like this:

```
EBV Acute EBV Acute Infection Antibodies
Reported: 11/23/2016 18:08   Status=F
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST                      RESULT               FLAG  RANGE       UNITS      SC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EBV Ab VCA, IgM           <36.0                      0.0-35.9     U/mL      RN      11/23/16.1808.rf
Negative        <36.0
Equivocal 36.0 - 43.9
Positive        >43.9
EBV Early Antigen Ab, IgG <9.0                       0.0-8.9      U/mL      RN      11/23/16.1808.rf
Negative        < 9.0
Equivocal  9.0 - 10.9
Positive        >10.9
EBV Ab VCA, IgG           <18.0                      0.0-17.9     U/mL      RN      11/23/16.1808.rf
Negative        <18.0
Equivocal 18.0 - 21.9
Positive        >21.9
EBV Nuclear Antigen Ab,   <18.0                      0.0-17.9     U/mL      RN      11/23/16.1808.rf
IgG
Negative        <18.0
Equivocal 18.0 - 21.9
Positive        >21.9
Interpretation:                                                             RN      11/23/16.1808.rf
```

---

As you can see, the result is not perfectly formatted. However, I believe it's the best you can do in the circumstances - unless you're willing to invest a lot of work in parsing the data into individual cells and presenting it in an HTML table. In any case, it *is* showing the data "as is" - for better or  worse.